# what is the difference extends type and type

Tags: scala

define Hello and World trait

```
trait Hello

trait World
```

this no problem

```
trait Right extends Hello with World
```

but this have a compile error

```
type HelloWorld = Hello with World

trait Error extends HelloWorld
//Error:(9, 22) class type required but A$A65.this.Hello with A$A65.this.World found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have a class or a trait after `extends`, and `Hello with World` is neither (it is a compound type). `extends Hello with World` should be understood as "extends `Hello` with `World`", not as "extends `Hello with World`".

Comment: as you say `trait Right extends (Hello with World)` it also compile error  ;think

Comment: The parentheses are only to make it clear, they aren't allowed. I changed the answer a bit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

By SLS 5.3, `trait Hello` is short for `trait Hello extends AnyRef` ("The `extends` clause [...] can be omitted, in which case `extends scala.AnyRef` is assumed").

And according to SLS 5.1, "It is possible to write a list of parents that starts with a trait reference [...] In that case the list of parents is implicitly extended to include the supertype of mt1 as first parent type."

Therefore `trait Right extends Hello with World` is actually short for `trait Right extends AnyRef with Hello with World`.

As for why using a type alias messes things up, if you look at the syntax definitions, the syntax isn't `extends <type>`, it's literally `extends <sc> with <mt1> with <mt2> ...`. The syntax for compound types is defined separately, in SLS 3.2.7. It looks like the same syntax, but it's not really the same.

Comment: thank you answer,i can tell the different between the two now